# App not showing up in "Complete action using..." menu even with an android filter with custom schema/host

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram-api, intentfilter

I'm trying to create a sign-in with Instagram feature for my Application.

I have the following code to make the client-side OAuth call to Instagram inside of my `LoginActivity`:

```
private void signInWithInstagram() {
    final Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
    uriBuilder.scheme("https")
            .authority("api.instagram.com")
            .appendPath("oauth")
            .appendPath("authorize")
            .appendQueryParameter("client_id", getString(R.string.instagram_client_id))
            .appendQueryParameter("redirect_uri", "https://<firebase-app-url>.cloudfunctions.net/redirect")
            .appendQueryParameter("response_type", "token");
    final Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriBuilder.build());
    startActivity(browser);
}
```

Above, `https://<firebase-app-url>.cloudfunctions.net/redirect` is a link to a firebase function that simply redirects me to `socialjournal://redirect`.

This happens when I press the "SIGN IN WITH INSTAGRAM" button below:
[image: Android Login Screen]

So, the web browser starts and takes me to Instagram, where I sign in. After Instagram redirects me to the specified link (which is my firebase function), my firebase function directs me to `socialjournal://redirect` (I do this since Instagram doesn't support custom schema URIs), which should be picked up by my `intent-filter` for the `LoginActivity`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.login.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="redirect"
            android:scheme="socialjournal"
            />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However, I am only presented with the following options for the link:

[image: Intent Filter not intercepting uri]

Shouldn't I see my App in the "Complete Action using..." list?

The uri that is being requested is something like `socialjournal://redirect#access_token=<some-long-and-obscure-code>`

What am I missing in this?

When I select Chrome, it attempts to redirect me to the URL, which fails. When I select Firefox, it opens my app, but it's not working (I've verified that the functions for dealing with the token aren't being called).

Comment: I'm not sure i understood you correctly. You expect browser to redirect to your app, right? So, why do you expect to open the original link with your app? The intent your app is sending is assumed for the browsers, but the intent the browsers will be sending is to be handled by your app

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev I don't expect to open the original link with my app. I am opening the link to Instagram with the first snippet of code (which will be in the browser), and the redirect URI _should_ be handled by the `intent-filter` (it should give me the option to open it with my app), but it doesn't appear to work that way.